# Bitfield write size

Tags: c, arm, c99, c11

I have a volatile struct/bitfield for a memory mapped register on an ARM processor.  The particular peripheral must be accessed by words.

```
struct
{
  unsigned field1 : 1;
  unsigned field2 : 3;
  unsigned field3 : 4;
  unsigned : 24;
} volatile my_variable __attribute__((section(".bss.my_periph")));
```

ARM Compiler V5 generates 32-bit accesses.  ARM Compiler V6 is smart enough to see that only field2 has changed and generates 8-bit accesses.  These 8-bit accesses break the world.

Is there a way to ensure that accesses are done by word?

I expect that something like this would work, but I would rather avoid the union:

```
union
{
  struct
  {
    unsigned field1 : 1;
    unsigned field2 : 3;
    unsigned field3 : 4;
    unsigned : 24;
  } fields;
  unsigned word;
} volatile my_variable __attribute__((section(".bss.my_periph")));
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171429/force-gcc-to-access-structs-with-words) help? Or are you not using gcc?

Comment: @JohnLedbetter ARM Compiler V6 (Clang) gives the error "unknown argument: '-fstrict-volatile-bitfields'"

Comment: you might investigate the assembly output from compiling with `-ffine-grained-bitfield-accesses` or `-fno-fine-grained-bitfield-accesses`.  Those look like they might control something similar, but the documentation around them is a bit sparse.   [Some other options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html) might be `-faapcs-bitfield-width` ("Follow the AAPCS standard requirement stating that volatile bit-field width is dictated by the field container type. ")

Comment: @JohnLedbetter None of those flags fixed my issue.  I did come up with a workaround.  Not as elegant as I would have liked, but functional.  When I have a minute I will post it as the answer to this question.  It is the expected solution with specific patterns for read, write, and read/modify/write.

Comment: The answer is entirely dependent on the particular compiler you use. This is not a question about the C language at all.

Comment: @mlp This is C language related.  How does the language specify accesses to volatile bitfields.  It appears that there it is not well specified.  Either it must access at the underlying type (`unsigned` here), or it must access at the narrowest type that holds the target field.  Older compilers didn't track dirty bits, only dirty words, therefore they couldn't do the optimization to only access the narrower type.

Comment: @Graznarak the C language deliberately leaves many things up to the Implementer (compiler writer). Particulars of bitfield access is one of those many things. The answer to your question is entirely dependent on the particular compiler you use. This is not a question about the C language at all.

Comment: Can I ask why 8-bit accesses causes issues? I found this SO discussion googling for "-ffine-grained-bitfield-access" information. FWIW, @JohnLedbetter answer works on x86:  https://godbolt.org/z/1hn8eoKnM

Comment: @GavinRay Note that this is specifically for memory mapped IO on 32-bit ARM.  Many memory mapped peripherals specify that access must be done with 32-bit operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the following works to force word-wise reads and writes.

Structure:

```
union my_type
{
  struct
  {
    unsigned field1 : 1;
    unsigned field2 : 3;
    unsigned field3 : 4;
    unsigned : 24;
  } fields;
  unsigned word;
} volatile my_variable __attribute__((section(".bss.my_periph")));
```

Read:

```
union my_type my_type;
my_type.word = my_variable.word;
return my_type.field2;
```

Write:

```
union my_type my_type = {0};
my_type.field3 = 5;
my_variable.word = my_type.word;
```

Read, Modify, Write:

```
union my_type my_type;
my_type.word = my_variable.word;
mytype.field2 = 7;
my_variable.word = my_type.word;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to ensure that accesses are done by word?

Yes, don't use bit-fields but `uint32_t`. Which also removes loads of other problems caused by bit-fields, such an undefined bit order, byte order, alignment, padding, "storage unit boundaries", integer types actually supported, signed vs unsigned and so on. The root of all such problems is the pretty much non-existent standardization of bit-fields.

Instead use bit-wise operators and masking. You could just go `my_var = THIS | THAT | ~(NOT_THAT);` and that's likely just fine for most use cases. Keep it simple.

If we insist on a more advanced, fancy solution, we could cook up more detailed macros - this is purposely a quite verbose solution but I just want to show the options:

```
// positions of fields within the bit-field
#define MYVAR_FIELD1_POS 31
#define MYVAR_FIELD2_POS 28
#define MYVAR_FIELD3_POS 24

// sizes of fields
#define MYVAR_FIELD1_SIZE 1
#define MYVAR_FIELD2_SIZE 3
#define MYVAR_FIELD3_SIZE 4

// bit masks based on sizes
#define MYVAR_FIELD1_MASK ((1u << MYVAR_FIELD1_SIZE)-1)
#define MYVAR_FIELD2_MASK ((1u << MYVAR_FIELD2_SIZE)-1)
#define MYVAR_FIELD3_MASK ((1u << MYVAR_FIELD3_SIZE)-1)

// bit masks with a value shifted to the correct position
#define MYVAR_FIELD1(val) ( ((val) & MYVAR_FIELD1_MASK) << MYVAR_FIELD1_POS )
#define MYVAR_FIELD2(val) ( ((val) & MYVAR_FIELD2_MASK) << MYVAR_FIELD2_POS )
#define MYVAR_FIELD3(val) ( ((val) & MYVAR_FIELD3_MASK) << MYVAR_FIELD3_POS )
```

This is how many of the more properly written register maps for microcontrollers work. Now you can just write:

```
my_var = MYVAR_FIELD1(1) | MYVAR_FIELD2(5) | MYVAR_FIELD3(15);
```

and you'll get `0xDF000000` (1 | 5 in first nibble then 0xF in next nibble). Benchmarking the above on gcc x86 for example yields a single instruction:

```
mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], -553648128
```

Where the magic number -553648128 = 0xDF000000.

Regarding single instruction, the above will boil down to an integer constant expression as long as we pass integer constants. If we pass variables, then it can't be calculated at compile time (bit-fields are no different here either). For such cases we should make a habit of using a temporary variable:

```
uint32_t tmp_var = MYVAR_FIELD1(x) | MYVAR_FIELD2(y) | MYVAR_FIELD3(z);
volatile my_var  = tmp_var; // access the volatile qualified variable on a line of its own
```

Comment: I have done much bitwise operations in the past.  It is very error prone in my experience, even with experienced developers.  My use of bitfields is based on the compiler-specified layouts.